# PrimeNG p-menubar with one model at the left and another on the right

Tags: primeng

I am using PrimeNG `p-menubar` and I need 2 models....one on the left and another on the right.

I've checked the documentation but cannot find anything.

I've got this code which added a model on the left.

```
<p-menubar [model]="items"></p-menubar>
```

I tried:

```
<p-menubar>
  <ng-template pTemplate="start">Left Model</ng-template>
  <ng-template pTemplate="end">Right Model</ng-template>
</p-menubar>
```

...but I cannot add `[model]="items"` to an `<ng-template>`

How do I do this?

Comment: Aren't we supposed to add `[model]="items"` to `<p-menubar>` rather than an `<ng-template>` ? As `Menubar` requires nested `menuitems` as its model. Refer [PrimeNG Menubar Documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/v10-lts/#/menubar)

Comment: Yes, but then I just get the one on the left which is default. I need one for the left and another for the right is: <p-menubar [model]="items" [model]="items2"> allowed?

Comment: I tried this but I only get the left one: <p-menubar [model]="items" [model]="items2"></p-menubar>

Answer (score 1):

You need to create two seperate Menubars and place them in its own div to align them next to each other:

```
<div>
  <div style="float: left;">
    <p-menubar [model]="items">
    </p-menubar>
  </div>
  <div style="float: left;">
    <p-menubar [model]="items2">
    </p-menubar>
  </div>
</div>
```